# QSerialPort::write() - only signed values? (127 decimal max)? I need to send 0xFF (255 dec)

Tags: c++, qt, qtserialport

Here is something I was not expecting. I need to write a little app that sends values over a serial port but the values are over 127. Upon looking at the Qt documentation here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtserialport/qserialport.html - unless I am missing something obvious, the QSerialPort::write() method does not seem to support anything higher than 127 (decimal).

I for instance happen to have a need to send 0xFF (255 decimal) so how do I send this when the methods only seem to support "signed" chars (again unless I am missing something). I was looking for a version of the write() methods that accept an "int" or an unsigned char which will let me go up to 255 in decimal.

```
virtual qint64  writeData(const char * data, qint64 maxSize)
```

See, there is no "unsigned char *" and there is no "int" so how do I send an array of 5 values where each of them is above 127 (dec)?

Comment: It's a pointer parameter anyway, so who cares?  Cast it anyway you want - writeData() will send it anyway.

Comment: Martin is right. It's a pointer to an array. Create an array, fill with your data call WriteData and it will go.

Comment: Hmm are you sure? I just tried this quick test: char *ptr = new char[5]; ptr[0] = 255; ShowMessage((int)ptr[0]); and I get -1. When I put "unsigned" in front of "char" and run the code again, I get 255. This is very important. The far end devices are projectors and screens etc so the data must be correct.

Comment: It is sending raw bytes over, so you can interpret it as you wish just like others wrote.

Answer (score 1):

It sends data as it is, and signed or unsigned is the problem of other side's interpretation.
-1 signed byte is 0xff, the same as 255 unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

You can still send bytes with values higher than 127. 
The signed char type just means that your data is passed to the method as an array of signed characters (so f.e unsigned 250 is equal to signed -6 but binary both are 250).

char *ptr = new char[5]; ptr[0] = 255; ShowMessage((int)ptr[0]);

From the beginning:

First of all check this wiki article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement (focus on 8-bit two's-complement integers table)

**The 2's complement code is the way how the negative values are written in a memory of your computer.**

Now:

The value 255 in binary code is written as 1111 1111.
The value -1 in 2's complement code is written also as 1111 1111.

So the unsigned or signed type of char, tells your compiler how to **deal** with this values (as signed or unsigned).

Now, what is happening when you try to convert from char or unsigned char to integer.

Now convert unsigned char to int: 
Your compiler **treats** 1111 1111 as 255 and convert it to 255 integer.

Now convert char to int:
Your compiler **treats** 1111 1111 as -1 and convert it to -1 integer.

The -1 integer has different binary code than -1 char value (because of the sign bit).